# Print timestamps in Docker Compose logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am seeing my `web` logs with `docker-compose logs web`, but I would like to add timestamps to those messages, because now they're quite out of context (don't know when did the event happen). I tried `docker-compose logs -t web`, but it seems Docker Compose is unaware of this flag.

Do you have any idea how can I make timestamps appear in Docker Compose logs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`docker-compose` now supports the `-t` argument, as pointed out by Ittiel.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions! I believe that the change isn't far away from Compose so probably I'll wait until then.

Comment: This answer is obsolete by now. I'd advise to unaccepted and accept Ittiel's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd delete, but it's still the accepted answer, so I've updated instead.

Answer (score 24):

docker-compose version 1.8.0 supports logs, you can use:

```
docker-compose logs -t
```